# Limit of $13^{a_n}=12^{a_{n-1}}+5^{a_{n-2}}$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence: $$13^{a_n}=12^{a_{n-1}}+5^{a_{n-2}},\;a_0=0,\;a_1=1.$$ I have to prove that it is monotone and bounded, and *I have to find the limit as $n\to\infty$*. It was for an older competition, but I cannot find an answer to it. I tried reformulating it to $$13^{a_n}=13^{a_{n-1}\alpha}+13^{a_{n-2}\beta},\;\alpha=\log_{13}12,\;\beta=\log_{13}5,$$
then with $b_n=13^{a_n}$ it is $$b_n=b_{n-1}^{\alpha}+b_{n-2}^{\beta}.$$ If it is the right way, how to proceed, if not, can you give me a hint how to start? I never looked deep into recurrence relations, but this is for first year engineering students, so advanced techniques are not needed I think.

Comment: Pythagoras might tell you that there is a value of $L$ for which $13^L=12^L+5^L$.  Of course that does not mean the sequence necessarily converges to this value of $L$; you would still have to prove the convergence.

Comment: I guess the limit will be 2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(5,12,13)$ is a Pythagorean triple.  $13^2 = 12^2 + 5^2$

Use induction to show that if $0<a_{n-2}<a_{n-1}<2$ then  $a_{n-1}<a_n<2$

Comment: I will try the induction tomorrow, thanks! As I understand it proves monotonicity and boundedness, and as a result the convergence. Is it necessary that 2 is the least upper bound, and it converges to this point (I am not familiar with theorems from this topic)?

Comment: As I look at it, I am not sure that induction was as easy as I had at first thought.  Nonetheless, that is the direction I would try first.

Comment: as it turned out, my teacher made this problem :) induction is the way to go!