# Sequence $13^{a_{n+2}}=12^{a_{n+1}}+5^{a_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let the sequence $(a_n)$, $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, and $13^{a_{n+2}}=12^{a_{n+1}}+5^{a_n}$. Prove that this sequence is convergent.

It is easy to observe that $a_n\in [0,2]$ so $a_n$ is a bounded sequence. Thus, it is only left to prove that it is monotone. I tried by induction (if $a_{n+1}>a_n$ I tried to prove $a_{n+2}>a_{n+1}$) but I failed. Can you please help me prove that the sequence is monotonous? Or help with any proof that the sequence converges. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of $13^{a_n}=12^{a_{n-1}}+5^{a_{n-2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699406/limit-of-13a-n-12a-n-15a-n-2)

Comment: No. I already said I tried induction but I failed. I still need help with it. Even though there exists another question of the same problem, it does not include the answer to the question in my post (which is how exactly do I prove the sequence is monotonous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
 a_{n+2} = f(a_{n+1}, a_n)
$$
where $f$ is a function which is increasing in both variables. So
$$
 a_n \le a_{n+1} \le a_{n+2}
$$
implies
$$ 
 a_{n+3}= f(a_{n+2}, a_{n+1}) \ge f(a_{n+1}, a_n) = a_{n+2} \,.
$$
So what you can show with induction is that
$$
 \forall n: \, a_n \le a_{n+1} \le a_{n+2} \, .
$$

Comment: Isn't the $\le$ sign in the 3rd equation looking at the wrong way?

Comment: @VIVID: Yes, I just had noticed it.

Comment: Very nice solution! I was trying this with quite a hard approach. Thanks for sharing.